# BCP exits with code 0

Tags: java, sql-server, command-line, bcp

When running BCP from my Java application it exits with status code 0 when 1 is expected.
I run bcp with an invalid combination of data and formatting file and bcp gives the following error:

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Invalid character value for cast  specification

BCP copy in failed
```

BCP however exits with exit code 0 and not 1, as i suspect. Now it is extremely difficult to see if something failed while running BCP. Exitting with the right code works once they match to some degree (like same delimiters).

Command

```
PS C:\Users\feh\Desktop> bcp integrate_test.dbo.AS_LOADER_DELIMITED in .\data.dat -S "10.0.0.161\SQL2K5,1048" -U user -P pass -f .\formatting.ctl -m 1

Starting copy...
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1
PS C:\Users\feh\Desktop> $lastexitcode
0
```

How can i validate a formatting file to the data and get a exit code 1 when they do not match?

Answer (score 0):

If the bcp is "in" the consider using [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx). This does the same as bcp but can be trapped using SQL Server TRY/CATCH or normal exception handling

Otherwise, are you trapping `%ERRORLEVEL%` and not some other code?

Comment: I've added the command i call with the result from $lastexitcode.

Answer (score 0):

In a batch file, need to `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` in order for the errorlevel environment variable will get set.